# Weird join on on behavior in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-execution-plan

I recently found old code that uses JOIN JOIN ON ON instead of the more familiar JOIN ON JOIN ON syntax.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (
    val INT
)
DECLARE @b TABLE (
    val INT
)
DECLARE @c TABLE (
    val INT
)


INSERT INTO @a VALUES (1),(2),(4)
INSERT INTO @b VALUES (1),(2),(4)
INSERT INTO @c VALUES (1),(2),(4)


SELECT *
FROM @a as a
join @b as b 
join @c as c
    on b.val = c.val    on a.val = b.val
```

What I find weird now is that if you consult the query plan, first a and c is joined but there is not even a join condition a.val = c.val.

Can anybody explain the implicit evaluation of this case?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it is query optimizer thing. First your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @a as a
join @b as b 
join @c as c
    on b.val = c.val
    on a.val = b.val;
```

Is the same as:

```
SELECT *
FROM @a AS A
JOIN ( @b AS B 
       JOIN @c AS C ON B.Val = C.Val
)  ON   A.Val = B.Val;
```

Second if you use hint:

> [FORCE ORDER](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/force-order-query-hint/)
>
> **When you put this query hint on to your query, it tells SQL Server that when it executes the statement to not change the order of the joins in the query.**  It will join the tables in the exact order that is specified in the query.
>
> Normally the SQL Server optimizer will rearrange your joins to be in the order that it thinks will be optimal for your query to execute.

```
SELECT *
FROM @a as a
join @b as b 
join @c as c
    on b.val = c.val
    on a.val = b.val  
    OPTION (FORCE ORDER);
```

You will get:

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. In the end the query optimization confused me more than it should. It makes much more sense with force order.

Still I think it is a bad style.. :)

Comment: I wouldn't really use `FORCE ORDER` only except when I'm 100% sure that the Optimizer wouldn't figure out on itself that it's more efficient to do the joins in the written order.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Force ORDER is to illustrate the OP way of thinking about joins. Here query optimizer uses different order and it was misleading(but still correct becasue a=b and b=c => a=c)

Comment: @lad2025 Agreed, fine with me then :)

Comment: @lad2025 pointed out, it is just for visualizing what happens. Of course I know my condition is implicit and query optimizer does its job. 
It heavily confused me though :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are joining:

- `@a` and `@b` and
- `@b` and `@c`

on the same `b.val` column, it's equivalent (and has better performance) if you just join these two tables together (on `a.val` = `c.val`) and then bring in everything from `@b` in the final result set.

Your join condition between `@a` and `@c` is not explicit, but implicit.

---

*Additional miscellaneous info:*

Also, since because you are joining table variables, it's most likely that the row estimates for each of the iterators in your execution plan (the table scans of `@a`, `@b` and `@c`) are going to be 1.

So, having this information around, SQL Server will most likely think that there's no reason to join `1 row` tables in any particular order. So on some executions you could get `@a` and `@b` joined in the bottom branch of the execution plan and in others you could get `@a` and `@c`.

*But this is just all speculation, what is certain is that the join conditions are implicit, but not explicit, which is why you're getting `@a` and `@c` joined first.*