# What does it mean when there are two ON conditions in an inner join and a table without any join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I came across a weird join condition and wanted help on this.

I have a SQL code like this and want to know what happens:

```
SELECT A.a,
       B.b
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
               ON A.a = B.b
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN C
                        INNER JOIN D
                                ON C.c = D.d
                        INNER JOIN E
                                ON D.d = E.e
                     ON C.c2 = A.a2
```

This works but I can't figure out what will happen in the above condition. Will C table be a right join or inner join? And what is the purpose of placing the on condition after an inner join. Does this make any difference?

What is the order of join execution on this?

Version: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird join on on behavior in tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460645/weird-join-on-on-behavior-in-tsql)

Comment: [What does the position of the ON clause actually mean?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/125422/3690)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite unorthodox to write `JOIN` conditions like this.  Although it is allowed, having two `ON` conditions together and not having an `ON` immediately following a `JOIN` is just confusing.

More so for people than SQL parsers, though.  When parsing complex joins, you can imagine that there are parentheses:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b
FROM (A INNER JOIN
      B
      ON A.a = B.b
     ) RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     (C INNER JOIN
      D
      ON C.c = D.d INNER JOIN
      E
      ON D.d = E.e
     )
     ON C.c2 = A.a2;
```

These parentheses are redundant.  They are showing how the SQL gets parsed.

Now your question is about the `RIGHT JOIN` condition and table `C`.  The `RIGHT JOIN` is to the result of the `INNER JOIN` on `C`, `D`, and `E`.

So, neither of these are true statements (in general):

- This is an "inner join" on `C`.
- This is a "right outer join" on `C`.

Because the outer join is to the result of the inner join on the three tables.

If you can, I would suggest rewriting the condition to be clearer!  At the very least, inserting the parentheses (although redundant) make the code easier for humans to understand.

Comment: Quite normal to do this when you need to `LEFT JOIN` the results of an `INNER JOIN`, in some circumstances there isn't any other way without using a derived table. I think `RIGHT JOIN` is more unorthodox, there is `RIGHT` that can't be a `LEFT`, so no-one really uses it. And the point you didn't make quite clear enough, and perhaps should, is that the parser ONLY looks at the order of the `ON` clauses, not what type of join it is